# How do I run ansible-test on the root of my collection?

Tags: ansible

I'm currently developing my own Ansible collection and following [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/dev_guide/developing_collections.html). The directory structure looks like this:

```
~/.ansible/collections/gertvdijk/mycollection
├── galaxy.yml
├── plugins
│   └── lookup
│       └── mylookup.py
├── README.md
└── tests
    └── unit
        └── plugins
            └── lookup
                └── test_mylookup.py
```

The location `~/.ansible/collections/gertvdijk/mycollection` is chosen for convenience so that it's found on the default search paths for collections ([COLLECTIONS_PATHS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/reference_appendices/config.html#collections-paths)).

The Ansible developer document [section *Testing collections*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/dev_guide/developing_collections.html#testing-collections) mentions that I should use `ansible-test` command from the root of my collection with the given structure.

> You must always execute `ansible-test` from the root directory of a collection.

However, that fails to me, with an error as if I should use this in a project already.
Even running `--help` fails with the current working directory error:

```bash
$ ansible-test --help
ERROR: The current working directory must be at or below:

 - an Ansible collection: {...}/ansible_collections/{namespace}/{collection}/

Current working directory: /home/gert/.ansible/collections/gertvdijk/mycollection
```

Same thing happens by cloning an existing community collection (e.g. [community.grafana](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.grafana)). The GitHub CI steps include an installation in a `ansible_collections/{namespace}/{collection}` path ([seen here](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.grafana/blob/770421f3f227f19c0cb227fdbf681be80d69225a/.github/workflows/ansible-test.yml#L14-L17)).

Taking that as a work-around for now (I'd like to avoid that); move the repository of the collection to *some path* that includes `/ansible_collections/gertvdijk/mycollection` and then run it from there.

This can't be true, right, that the directory name two levels up make or break the `ansible-test` tool? What am I missing here?

Comment: Actually, the directories listed in `COLLECTION_PATH` are expected to contain a top level `ansible_collections` folder. This is exactly how a blank folder gets structured if you use `ansible-galaxy collection install -p /whatever community.grafana` => you end up with `/whatever/ansible_collections/community/grafana`. So your actual home folder collection path should be `/home/gert/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/gertvdijk/mycollection`.

Comment: @Zeitounator Wow, that's confusing and I totally missed that. Thanks, it worked. Would you like to make that an answer? I'm happy to upvote that.

Comment: Comment upgraded to answer as proposed with some minor additional info. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The path for your home collection should be `/home/gert/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/gertvdijk/mycollection`

---

The directories listed in `COLLECTION_PATH` are actually expected to contain a top level `ansible_collections` folder. This is linked to the `ansible_collections` convention used by e.g. [`module_utils` as explained in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_collections.html#module-utils)

You can also observe how a blank folder gets structured by running e.g.

```
ansible-galaxy collection install -p /whatever community.grafana
```

In this case, you will end up with the folder `/whatever/ansible_collections/community/grafana`.

So your actual home folder collection path should be `/home/gert/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/gertvdijk/mycollection`